# log4j2 fish tagging logs for all interactions of same user

Tags: java, log4j2

i am using ThreadContext to tag all logs with a UUID in my java web app. I am using a filter to do so, with this code in the doFilter method , to tag every request.

```
     if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest){
         ThreadContext.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
     }
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

This changes in every new request that is performed, which is normal since it is called in every request. What i would like to do is to have the same tag for all interaction of the same session/user/interaction with the app.

I thought about adding the username in the ThreadContext, and checking every time to see if the session username is different from what i have in the thread context, but since ThreadContext is thread safe and a new thread is generated for each request, this does not work.

How would you go about doing that?

Is there any standard way in log4j2?

Also, is this the idea of fish tagging, or it is not fit for such a task??

Comment: I have no problem with receiving downvotes, but please state some reason for it. Let me know whats wrong.

Comment: I upvoted since think your question is perfectly legit and yes this is the idea of fish tagging. Can you clarify what problem you are experiencing? How do you expect the logging to behave and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for upvote, and for answering. The main thing is i want to have the same ID for all the interactions of the user with the app, in the same session. I think i completely misunderstood ThreadContext, what i am doing now is getting the id from the session, and setting it as the fish tag in THreadContext via a filter, in oder to have the same id in the logs for all the session. I thought that the THreadContext could be easily extended to include all the interactions of the user.

Comment: Is this not working? What does the log output look like?

Comment: Yes, it is working as i described above, thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Is the problem resolved? If not, can you add more detail?

Comment: Hi Remko, the ThreadContext is working now as expected. I would like to set ThreadContext Values from a JSF managed bean. Do you see any problems with that?